# Recognizing File Extension , Printing with different color to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I can recognize file extensions but still cant give different color for different extensions  when I am printing to TextArea , is it because TextArea and all the font changes after running the program to *"serif", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 5*

```
  public void setScanResult(ArrayList<String> x) {


    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {

        if (x.get(i).endsWith(".txt")) {

            Font fono1 = new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 50);
            textArea.setFont(fono1);
            textArea.append((String) x.get(i));
        } else if (x.get(i).endsWith(".xls")) {

            Font fono2 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, 10);
            textArea.setFont(fono2);
            textArea.append((String) x.get(i));
        } else {

            Font fono3 = new Font("serif", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 5);
            textArea.setFont(fono3);
            textArea.append((String) x.get(i));
        }
        textArea.append("\n");
        //textArea.append((String) x.get(i));

    }

    x.clear();
```

Comment: JTextArea doesn't support multiple fonts for different fragments of text. Use JTextPane instead. For the simplest case just insert HTML to show desired formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTextArea` is for plain text, not formatted.  That means that at any moment, it can have one font, at one size, in one color.

If the app. needs formatted text, look to `JEditorPane` or [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html).  See [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for details and working source.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try to switch this